# Map that could be iterated in the order of values

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, guava, apache-commons

I need a Map that could be iterated in the decreasing **order of its values**. Does any of the standard libraries like Apache Commons or Guava provide this kind of map ?

Comment: The standard Java library has an extension of the `Map` interface that is sorted called SortedMap: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html You can then just pick a concrete implementation of the `SortedMap` interface

Comment: I find it odd that you want to have the decreasing order of *values* - do you really want that or did you mean *keys*?

Comment: @nd: yes I'm sure I really want that

Comment: SortedMap orders keys, not values - it's stated on firts line of its documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do this with Guava as follows:

```
Ordering<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> entryOrdering = Ordering.from(valueComparator)
  .onResultOf(new Function<Entry<Key, Value>, Value>() {
    public Value apply(Entry<Key, Value> entry) {
      return entry.getValue();
    }
  }).reverse();
// Desired entries in desired order.  Put them in an ImmutableMap in this order.
ImmutableMap.Builder<Key, Value> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
for (Entry<Key, Value> entry : 
    entryOrdering.sortedCopy(map.entrySet())) {
  builder.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
return builder.build();
// ImmutableMap iterates over the entries in the desired order
```

Comment: could you clarify how do I define this valueComparator ?

Comment: @user it's [`Comparator<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) you want to use in first place. If values implement `Comparable`, then you can use [`Ordering.natural()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#natural()) instead of custom `valueComparator`.

Comment: `Ordering.from(Ordering.natural())...` leads to a deprecated function call, there is a alternative method which asks for a comparator type argument instead. My values are actually of type `Integer`. Could you suggest what comparator should I pass for integer values sorting? Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't use Ordering.from(Ordering.natural()), just use Ordering.natural() directly.

Answer (score 12):

With guava, there is even cleaner way than @LoisWasserman's anwer - using Ordering combined with [`Functions.forMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#forMap%28java.util.Map%29):

```
Ordering.natural().reverse().nullsLast().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(map, null))
```

or if values aren't `Comparable`:

```
Ordering.fromComparator(yourComparator).reverse().nullsLast().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(map, null))
```

An example (with first option - natural ordering):

```
final Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    "key 1", "value 1",
    "key 2", "value 2",
    "key 3", "another value",
    "key 4", "zero value");

final Ordering<String> naturalReverseValueOrdering =
    Ordering.natural().reverse().nullsLast().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(map, null));

System.out.println(ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(map, naturalReverseValueOrdering));
```

outputs:

```
{key 4=zero value, key 2=value 2, key 1=value 1, key 3=another value}
```

(I use [ImmutableSortedMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html) here, but [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) can also be used if mutability is required.)

**EDIT**:

If there are identical values (more exactly if there are two values for which `Comparator.compare(String v1, String v2)` returns 0) ImmutableSortedMap throws an exception. Ordering must not return, so i.e. you should order map by values first and keys next if both values are equal (keys aren't supposed to be equal) by using [`Ordering.compound`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound%28java.util.Comparator%29):

```
final Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(
    "key 1", "value 1",
    "key 2", "value 2",
    "key 3", "zero value",
    "key 4", "zero value");

final Ordering<String> reverseValuesAndNaturalKeysOrdering =
    Ordering.natural().reverse().nullsLast().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(map, null)) // natural for values
        .compound(Ordering.natural()); // secondary - natural ordering of keys

System.out.println(ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(map, reverseValuesAndNaturalKeysOrdering));
```

prints:

```
{key 3=zero value, key 4=zero value, key 2=value 2, key 1=value 1}
```

Comment: this leads to illegal argument exception incase two keys are set with same value...

Comment: @user that's because comparing them returns 0 (suggesting equality, what's correct) and ImmutableSortedMap treats that as exceptional case (what should it do? entry: `key1=same_value` first or rather `key2=same_value` first?). Comparator **must not** return 0 in this case, edited my answer and example (but remember - it's for Strings!).

Comment: I'm really fundamentally uncomfortable with this solution, specifically because your ImmutableSortedMap won't just return null on keys that aren't in the map: it'll fail completely, because the comparator doesn't apply.

Comment: @LouisWasserman isn't this enough when same `map` is used in `Functions.forMap` and `ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf` constructor?

Comment: It's enough to make the ImmutableSortedMap creation work fine, yes.  And then it'll explode in your face when you try to query the `ImmutableSortedMap` later on and have no idea why it's throwing weird exceptions.

That is, `map.get(keyNotInTheMap)` will throw an exception.  Ew.

Comment: @LouisWasserman ah, that's your point! `Functions.forMap(map, null)` should be used then.

Comment: That's still iffy and bug-prone, since then you need your comparator to be able to deal with nulls.  And that's all setting aside the potential cost of calling map.get every time you do a comparison.  This approach as a whole is just much more prone to things going wrong in subtle and unexpected ways. =/

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added `.nullsLast()` to comparator and now I surrender :) Treat this answer as narrow (works quite fine in ImmutableSortedMap) unconventional use of `Functions.forMap` (it must have some purpose in library) for getting values of map for keys while using comparator.

Comment: I _think_ the modified answer is correct, but as a general rule, if you can avoid writing code that can go wrong in many subtle ways, you should always do so.

Answer (score 2):

This can now be done in a single line using [Java 8 Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```java
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple method to get an immutable copy of your map sorted by descending value. Remove the call to `reverse()` if you want ascending order. Requires [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

```
private Map<String, String> mapSortedByValues(Map<String, String> theMap) {
    final Ordering<String> ordering =
            Ordering.natural().reverse().nullsLast().onResultOf(Functions.forMap(theMap, null));

    return ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(theMap, ordering);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`DualTreeBidiMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/DualTreeBidiMap.html) of Apache Commons Collections should make this possible, probably by iterating over the return from `inverseBidiMap()`.

But I don't think this allows for duplicate values - as the name says, the structure is simply based on keeping *two* trees, which is really the only thing that makes sense, since values in a map have no meaning to the map structure.

Comment: You don't need two trees. You could have one `Map` for the key-values, and an ordered `List` of values (or of `Map.Entry`s if you need that).

Comment: @yshavit: you could, if you have a list structure that is both auto-ordered and allows efficient insertion and deletion, which is not simple (I think it can be done with a skip list). Why the extra complexity if you already have one tree?

Comment: because, as you point out, it doesn't allow for duplicate values. If that's a requirement, the two-`Map` approach is disqualified. And you don't need a `List` that manages the order for you, you can just manually ensure the ordering on inserts as an invariant. But anyway, I agree it's more complexity, and should only be done if you need those duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the values also in TreeSet ?

```
for(;;) { yourMap.put(key,value); }
SortedSet sortedValues = new TreeSet(yourMap.values());
```

or

```
SortedSet sortedValues = new TreeSet();
for(;;) 
{
yourMap.put(key,value);
sortedValued.add(value);
}
```

Comment: What to do with duplicated values?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put entries on the list and sort it. I don't recall any map that can be ordered by values, only by keys. You could use BiMap from Guava, but it requires values uniqueness.

Example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("key1", "value1");
            put("key2", "value3");
            put("key3", "value4");
            put("key4", "value2");
        }};

        List<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<String, String> o1,
                    Entry<String, String> o2) {
                if (o1.getValue() == null && o2.getValue() == null) return 0;
                if (o1.getValue() == null) return -1; //Nulls last
                return - o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to roll your own implementation of such a map. Fortunately, it shouldn't be much of an issue with Guava:

```
public class SortedValueMap<K, V> extends ForwardingMap<K, V> {

  private Map<K, V> delegate = newHashMap();
  private Comparator<V> valueComparator;

  public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> SortedValueMap<K, V> reverse() {
    return new SortedValueMap<K, V>(Ordering.<V> natural().reverse());
  }

  public static <K, V> SortedValueMap<K, V> create(Comparator<V> valueComparator) {
    return new SortedValueMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
  }

  protected SortedValueMap(Comparator<V> valueComparator) {
    this.valueComparator = checkNotNull(valueComparator);

  }

  @Override
  protected Map<K, V> delegate() {
    return delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<K> keySet() {
    return new StandardKeySet();
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
    TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> result = newTreeSet(new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
        return ComparisonChain.start()
            .compare(o1.getValue(), o2.getValue(), valueComparator)
            .compare(o1.getKey(), o2.getKey(), Ordering.arbitrary())
            .result();
      }

    });
    result.addAll(Collections.unmodifiableMap(delegate).entrySet());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<V> values() {
    return new StandardValues();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortedValueMap<String, String> svm = SortedValueMap.reverse();
    svm.put("foo", "1");
    svm.put("bar", "3");
    svm.put("baz", "2");

    System.out.println(Joiner.on(", ").withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(svm));
    System.out.println(Joiner.on(", ").join(svm.values()));
    System.out.println(Joiner.on(", ").join(svm.keySet()));
  }
}
```

Fail-fast iterators are not present in this implementation; please add them for yourself if required. Please also note that setting a value via Map.Entry.setValue would cause havoc with the sort order, which is why I used `unmodifyableMap` in entry set.