# How to sort a TreeMap by (Date) values?

Tags: java, treemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)
>   [Map that could be iterated in the order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896679/map-that-could-be-iterated-in-the-order-of-values)

I have a TreeMap of type `<String, Date>`. I want to sort it by the Dates (most recent first), and I can't use them as the keys as I cannot guarantee that they will be unique. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Nambari, the answer to that question doesn't work when values are non-unique.

Comment: @Louis, why shouldn't it work when the values are non-unique?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Ok. Actually I was looking for your answer, but thought link I have does same job. I am removing it.

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld's linked solution also fails _really weirdly_ for duplicate values.  Look at the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't directly do it, what you can do is to copy the content of the collection into a new one and then sort it, eg:

```
List<Map.EntrySet<String, Date>> copy = new ArrayList<Map.EntrySet<String, Date>>(treeMap.entrySet());
Collections.sort(copy, new CustomComparator());

class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Date>> {
  public int compareTo(Map.Entry<String,Date> e1, Map.Entry<String,Date> e2) {
    // compare your dates
  }
}
```

Of course this collection won't be synced with the original one so you must do it again every time the original `TreeSet` is modified.

Comment: Is the comaprsion and sort based on todays date? Like a birth day thing?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can have duplicate keys in TreeMap if you really want it

```
    Map<Date, String> map = new TreeMap<Date, String>(new Comparator<Date>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Date d1, Date d2) {
            return d1.after(d2) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    });
    Date d1 = new Date(-100000000000L);
    Date d2 = new Date(100000000000L);
    map.put(d2, "s1");
    map.put(d1, "s2");
    map.put(d1, "s3");
    System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{Mon Oct 31 16:13:20 EET 1966=s3, Mon Oct 31 16:13:20 EET 1966=s2, Sat Mar 03 11:46:40 EET 1973=s1}
```

Note that 2 entries have the same key, and output is sorted by Date as you wanted

Comment: A `Map` by definition cannot have two values for one key. What am I missing?

Comment: Comparator used in the test allows it. All depends on Comparator annd your desire, you can make TreeMap think that 2 is less than 1 if need be.

Comment: Oh, your comparator never returns 0.

Comment: So you can put things into this map and iterate it but can't get anything from it, amirite?

Comment: Of course get() does not make sense. You cant get 2 values with one get