# Why does this Guava Ordering of a Map by value work?

Tags: java, generics, guava

I'm new to the Guava library and trying to use some of its classes to simplify my code.  I've run across the need to sort a Map by value.  A quick search found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897384/827480) which posts an accepted answer as the following code snippet:

```
Ordering<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> entryOrdering = Ordering.from(valueComparator)
  .onResultOf(new Function<Entry<Key, Value>, Value>() {
    public Value apply(Entry<Key, Value> entry) {
      return entry.getValue();
    }
  }).reverse();
// Desired entries in desired order.  Put them in an ImmutableMap in this order.
ImmutableMap.Builder<Key, Value> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
for (Entry<Key, Value> entry : 
    entryOrdering.sortedCopy(map.entrySet())) {
  builder.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
return builder.build();
// ImmutableMap iterates over the entries in the desired order
```

Can someone please clarify for me how this works?  I am failing to understand something.

The definition of Ordering is `Ordering<T>`.  In this case `<T>` would be `Map.Entry`.  Furthermore, the method signature of `onResultOf` is `onResultOf(Function<F,? extends T> function)`.

In the above code, `onResultOf` is being called with the following parameter:

```
onResultOf(new Function<Entry<Key, Value>, Value>())
```

Which in this case would imply that:

```
<F> = Entry<Key, Value>
<? extends T> = Value
```

Which in turn implies that `Value` is a type that would extend a `Map.Entry`.

How is that possible?  How can `Value` be a type that would extend `Map.Entry`, when the entry map contains Key, Value?

I am sure I am misreading or misunderstanding something, but if anyone can shed some light on this, I am hoping it will help me understand Guava and the Ordering() class a little better.  Especially how the `onResultOf(Function)` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature of `onResultOf` is:

```
public <F> Ordering<F> onResultOf(Function<F,? extends T> function)
```

The `F` takes the place of `T`. To match the previous definition it should be rewritten as

```
public <T> Ordering<T> onResultOf(Function<T,? extends U> function)
```

So the parameter to `onResultOf` is actually `Function< Map.Entry<Key, Value>, ? extends U >` and therefore, the second parameter doesn't have to extend `Map.Entry`

Answer (score 3):

There are three different Orderings being created here, one of which has a different type than the others.  Your code code be rewritten as:

```
Ordering<Value> valueOrdering = Ordering.from(valueComparator);
Ordering<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> entryOrdering = valueOrdering
     .onResultOf(new Function<Entry<Key, Value>, Value>() {
         public Value apply(Entry<Key, Value> entry) {
            return entry.getValue();
         }
});
Ordering<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> finalOrdering = entryOrdering.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confused by the fact, that the class `Ordering` is declared as `Ordering<T>`, but the return value of the `onResultOf` method is `Ordering<F>`.

The first type argument of the `Function`, you are providing to `onResultOf` is the type argument of the result.

That also means, that `Value` is not forced to be a subtype of `Map.Entry`.