# ImmutableSortedMap - Duplicate keys in mappings

Tags: java, sorting, guava, comparator

I have an ImmutableSortedMap that holds data in the following datastructure.

```
<String, Pair<Long, Double>>
```

My goal is to sort this map in descending order starting with the largest `Double` and if two `Doubles` are the same, sort it by the `Long`. If both the `Double` and `Long` are the same, sort it by `String`

My current comparator only deals with the first case, and looks like this.

```
private ImmutableSortedMap<String, Pair<Long, Double>> sortInDescendingSizeOrder(final Map<String, Pair<Long, Double>> statsByType) {
    Ordering<String> ordering = Ordering
            .from(new Comparator<Pair<Long, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Pair<Long, Double> o, Pair<Long, Double> o2) {
                    return o.getRight().equals(o2.getRight()) ? o.getLeft().compareTo(o2.getLeft()) : o.getRight().compareTo(o2.getRight());
                }
            })
            .reverse()
            .onResultOf(Functions.forMap(statsByType, null));

    return ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(statsByType, ordering);
}
```

However, it finds two `Doubles` that are the same and throws the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate keys in mappings`

I don't understand what am I doing wrong...

EDIT: I have tried to add the `compound` method and order by String (at least).

```
.compound(new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return o1.compareTo(o2);
                    }
                });
```

This makes the code not throw any Exception, however, there is no ordering whatsoever in the resulted map.

EDIT 2: At this point, any ordering like the one described above of a

```
Map<String, Pair<Long, Double>>
```

will do. Doesn't necessarily need to be an ImmutableSortedMap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: [See Louis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746478/708434) for *actual* proper solution ([`ImmutableMap.Builder#orderEntriesByValue(Comparator)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html#orderEntriesByValue-java.util.Comparator-)). Continue reading this answer for fix of an incorrect approach ;)

---

It's a documented behavior of [`ImmutableSortedMap#copyOf(Map, Comparator)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html#copyOf-java.util.Map-java.util.Comparator-):

> Throws:
>
> `NullPointerException` - if any key or value in map is null
>   `IllegalArgumentException` - **if any two keys are equal according to the comparator**

What you get is a result of values being equal according to comparator, so the problem is there. [See this answer for comparing map by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899689/708434) - as Louis mentions (he's from Guava team), using `Functions.forMap` is tricky.

In your case adding `.nullsLast()` to first ordering and appending `.compound(Ordering.natural())` should work. For example:

```
Map<String, Pair<Long, Double>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
        "a", Pair.of(1L, 1.0d),
        "b", Pair.of(1L, 1.0d),
        "c", Pair.of(1L, 1.0d),
        "d", Pair.of(1L, 1.0d)
);

@Test
public void should2()
{
    final ImmutableSortedMap<String, Pair<Long, Double>> sortedMap = sortInDescendingSizeOrder(map);
    assertThat(sortedMap).hasSize(4);
    System.out.println(sortedMap); // {a=(1,1.0), b=(1,1.0), c=(1,1.0), d=(1,1.0)}
}
```

and for

```
Map<String, Pair<Long, Double>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
        "a", Pair.of(1L, 1.0d),
        "b", Pair.of(2L, 1.0d),
        "c", Pair.of(1L, 2.0d),
        "d", Pair.of(2L, 2.0d)
);
```

it outputs `{d=(2,2.0), b=(2,1.0), c=(1,2.0), a=(1,1.0)}`.

(`sortInDescendingSizeOrder` for reference)

```
private ImmutableSortedMap<String, Pair<Long, Double>> sortInDescendingSizeOrder(
        final Map<String, Pair<Long, Double>> statsByType) {
    Ordering<String> ordering = Ordering.from(new Comparator<Pair<Long, Double>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Pair<Long, Double> o, Pair<Long, Double> o2) {
                    return ComparisonChain.start()
                            .compare(o.getRight(), o2.getRight())
                            .compare(o.getLeft(), o2.getLeft())
                            .result();
                }
            })
            .reverse()
            .nullsLast()
            .onResultOf(Functions.forMap(statsByType, null))
            .compound(Ordering.natural());

    return ImmutableSortedMap.copyOf(statsByType, ordering);
}
```

[`ComparisonChain`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html) is another goodie from Guava you can use here.

Comment: Ordering is still messed up... There is absolutely no ordering, not on the Double, Long or String

Comment: I edited answer and added input map containing `{a=(1,1.0),b=(2,1.0),c=(1,2.0),d=(2,2.0)}` and output looks good to me: `{d=(2,2.0), b=(2,1.0), c=(1,2.0), a=(1,1.0)}`. Can you post sample data you put in and what's your expected output?

Comment: It works, I had an error somewhere else. Thanks @Xaerxess

Comment: The resulting map is still going to throw on `get(keyNotInMap)`.  Using `ImmutableSortedMap` at all is not really a good idea here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yep, `.nullsLast()` was missing. As as cited, it's tricky - added reference to your simpler answer.

Answer (score 3):

`ImmutableSortedMap` is *not* the correct API for this.  `ImmutableSortedMap` is supposed to be sorted by *keys*, and that's clearly not what you're doing.

What would make more sense is writing

```
new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Pair<Long, Double>>()
   .orderEntriesByValue(comparing(Pair::getSecond).thenComparing(Pair::getFirst))
   .putAll(map)
   .build();
```

though, if you can't use Java 8, you'll have to explicitly write the comparator

```
new Comparator<Pair<Long, Double>>() {
  @Override public int compare(Pair<Long, Double> a, Pair<Long, Double> b) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
        .compare(a.getSecond(), b.getSecond())
        .compare(a.getFirst(), b.getFirst())
        .result();
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding `ImmutableMap.Builder#orderEntriesByValue` - that neat (haven't seen this, it's `@since 19.0`)! OP wants sort on both pair values and seems to be on Java <7, so `ComparisonChain` seems right here.